# Extending DataGridColumn and specifying paddingLeft

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, mxml

I'm tring to Extend DataGridColumn, and in the extending class, trying
to specify a value for paddingLeft, but I am unable to compile it.

Using Flex Builder 3 :

mainApp.mxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:DataGrid x="191" y="171">
        <mx:columns>
            <local:DataGridColumnExt headerText="Column 1" dataField="col1"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

DataGridColumnExt.mxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:DataGridColumn xmlns="*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" paddingLeft="10">
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Error I get :
Access of possibly undefined property styleDeclaration through a reference with static type DataGridColumnExt. [Generated code (use -keep to save): Path: DataGridColumnExt-generated.as, Line: 68, Column: 13]     DataGridColumnWithLeftPadding   Unknown 1290353024334   24677

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to extend `DataGridColumn` in order to change the padding and as you've already noticed setting the style `paddingLeft` in your `DataGridColumnExt` doesn't work. I guess it doesn't work since the `DataGridColumn` works only as a proxy for the styles. The column's item renderer derives its styles from the column. So, you have a few options to accomplish what you are trying to do (see my example below):

1. Use `mx:DataGridColumn` and set the desired styles like `paddingLeft` on it. The column's item renderer will use the padding (see "Column 1" in my example).
2. Create your own item renderer (you could extend `mx:DataGridItemRenderer`, set the styles directly in the item renderer and set the column's `itemRenderer` property accordingly  (see "Column 2" in my example).
3. In case you often need to use the same column with the same styles it would make sense to create your own `DataGridColumn` and set your `itemRenderer` within your custom column  (see "Column 3" in my example).

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:local="*">
    <mx:DataGrid x="191" y="171" dataProvider="{[{value: 'foo'}, {value : 'bar'}]}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="value" paddingLeft="20"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="value" itemRenderer="ItemRendererWithPadding"/>
            <local:DataGridColumnExt headerText="Column 3" dataField="value"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:Application>
```

**ItemRendererWithPadding.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:DataGridItemRenderer xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" paddingLeft="20">
</mx:DataGridItemRenderer>
```

**DataGridColumnExt.as**

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;

    public class DataGridColumnExt extends DataGridColumn
    {
        public function DataGridColumnExt(columnName:String = null)
        {
            super(columnName);
            itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(ItemRendererWithPadding);
        }
    }
}
```